# XSLT step-by-step debugger

Tags: debugging, xslt

I know this question is like one posed before, but I need a good xslt debugger that allows me to step through xsl transformation as they happen. I had oxygen and really liked its capabilities but my trial lincense ran out. Anyone know of another good one for this purpose? Preferably completely free, but if its a trial version still its better than nothing. I am running mac osx but I don't want to just get a new license for one of my vm's because I don't want to have to keep switching back and forth and I'm not sure how stable the network mapping on my vm is and it might take awhile to allow it to access the network drive I want. Any help or suggestions are appreciated.

Comment: You know, the best things in life are not always free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Visual Studio can do this quite well. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms255605%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) for details. I think you'll be able to do it with [VS express](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/en-us/products/2010-editions/express), which is free.

Comment: Even though Mono seems to provide some rudimentary tools for such a task http://www.oreillynet.com/xml/blog/2008/01/mono_projecthidden_gems_monoxs.html you can try this beast for 30 days: http://www.editix.com/ On the other hand, if you have enough RAM, you could run a Windows virtual machine with Visual Studio inside :)

Comment: That's as good of an answer as I could find anywhere for mac free tools. I ended up just biting the bullet and running out of my vm, kind of inconvenient but it works.